# How do I display the first name only?

Tags: arrays, java.util.scanner, displaytag

the data.txt file contains:

```
Manyana, Michael, 30
Henderson, Marge, 22
Striker, Nancy, 32
Johnson, Fred, 12
Ryan, Renee, 22
```

I would like to know how to display the first name only and store it into a new array. How do I select the first name only? Eg,

```
Manyana
Henderson
Striker
Johnson
Ryan
```

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class multipleArray {
   private static Scanner file;

   public static String[] array = new String[500];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File myfile = new File("data.txt");
        file = new Scanner (myfile);
        Scanner s = file.useDelimiter(",");
        int i = 0;
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            i++;
            array[i] = s.next();
        }

        for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++) {
        if(array[j] == null)
            ;
        else
            System.out.print(array[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing `i` in your `while` loop and after that you don't reset it therefore in your `for` loop you see the final value of `i`.

You should do something like this:

```
for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++)
        System.out.print(array[j]);
```

Comment: Oops. That was a silly mistake. Thanks but since the array contains value of 500 therefore it displays null repeatedly after the strings from the file.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. But how do I display the first name only?

Answer (score 0):

First of all by only using "," as a delimiter you never select the first name. This would need further splitting which could be avoided.

```
Scanner s = file.useDelimiter(","); //array[2]=="30\nHenderson" !
```

Should instead be :

```
Scanner s = file.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
```

Then you can simply print the first names this way :

```
for(int j=0; j<i; j+=3) {
     System.out.println(array[j]);
}
```

Also by doing the following you leave the first string of your array empty...

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    i++;
    array[i] = s.next();
}
```

I would suggest :

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    array[i] = s.next();
    i++;
}
```